# Except one folder from preventing access by .htaccess file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, permissions

In .htaccess file I use `Options -Indexes` command but I wanna except one folder called 'test' from that command. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new file inside `test/` as `/test/.htaccess` and place this line:

```
Options +Indexes
```